Are sample mean and variance unique estimators?
I get that the sample mean and sample variance are unbiased and consistent estimators.
But i'm wondering if they are unique estimators that are unbiased and consistent.
i.e. for any statistic A, if A is a consistent and unbiased estimator of the population mean, A is the sample mean.
And likewise for the sample variance as well.
I want to know if these statements are true and how to prove/disprove it.
Please help me. thanks

Not sure what you mean.  What does "consistent" mean?  You could add any noise with mean $0$ to the estimator and get another unbiased estimator.

If $T_n$ is an unbiased and consistent estimator of $\theta$, i.e $\mathbb{E}(T_n) = \theta, T_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} \theta$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then, define
$$
    \tilde{T}_n = T_n + R_n
$$
where $R_n$ is any random variable, such that $\mathbb{E}\vert R_n \vert < \infty, \mathbb{E}(R_n) = 0, R_n \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. ($R_n$ may even depends on $T_n$). Then, $\tilde{T}_n$ is also an unbiased and consistent estimator.
One such example for $R_n$ is $R_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, a_n)$, where $a_n > 0, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$. Thus, if there exists an unbiased, consistent estimator for $\theta$, there will be an infinite number of estimators that is also unbiased and consistent for $\theta$ (this applies for the sample mean and sample variance)
